# Cannot get a simple text_area character counter working

Tags: javascript, jquery

assuming a form with class "store_edit" and id "store_edit_4" and a field store.description

is there a straightforward way to add a character counter in rails 3 now that they've removed the handy field_observer?

Just want a counter to increase with each character they type...

---

I tried several approaches in several blogs but to no avail. This one is a simple but a little goofy, displaying the char count in an input box instead of stuffing a div tag, but even that I could not get to work using the same field names etc. For example, I put this in my (formerly empty) application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var code = document.code_search.search;
    var remaining = document.code_search.remLen1;

    function textCounting(field,cntfield,maxlimit) {
      if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
        field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
        // Set the value
        // otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
      else
        cntfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
    }
  $('#test').keydown(function(){textCounting(code, remaining, 5)});       
  $('#test').keyup(function(){textCounting(code, remaining, 5)});   
});
```

added this haml above all my regular stuff (just to test it for the same field names etc as in the a blog)

```
= form_tag store_path, :method => 'get', :id => "code_search", :name => "code_search" do
  %p
    = text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :size => '5', :id => 'test'
    %input{:maxlength => "3", :name => "remLen1", :readonly => "", :size => "3", :type => "text", :value => "5"}
      characters left
```

and my html right below the body tag looks like this:

```
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/stores/AHPGKIUA" id="code_search" method="get" name="code_search"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>
    <p>
      <input id="test" name="search" size="5" type="text" />
      <input maxlength='3' name='remLen1' readonly='' size='3' type='text' value='5'>

        characters left
      </input>
    </p>
  </form>
```

And the head of my html does include application.js

And I restarted webrick, emptie my browser's cache...

but when I type into the field, the char counted doesn't change.

Is there SOME reasonably straightforward way to add basic char counting in Rails 3?

Comment: Your problem seems to be with jQuery, not Rails.

Comment: That is correct. I reinstalled and that made a difference! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using jQuery and Haml (which I assume you are, based on your question), here is a working example:

```
= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :size => 5, :id => 'test'
%br
%span#char_count 140 characters left
:javascript

  // just a function to pluralize the word "characters" based on the number
  function pluralize_characters(num) {
    if(num == 1) {
      return num + " character";
    } else {
      return num + " characters";
    }
  }

  $("#test").keyup(function() {
    var chars = $("#test").val().length;
    var left = 140 - chars; // sub 140 for your max length
    if(left >= 0) {
      $("#char_count").text(pluralize_characters(left) + " left");
    } else {
      left = left * (-1)
      $("#char_count").text(pluralize_characters(left) + " too long");
    }
  });
```

Based on [this code](https://github.com/BinaryMuse/rails-book/blob/master/app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.haml).

Answer (score 2):

if its an option you can use various jQuery character count plugins...

- [character count plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/character-counter)
- [another char count plugin](http://roy-jin.appspot.com/jsp/textareaCounter.jsp)

also you can try out the following code

```
// controls character input/counter
$('textarea#body').keyup(function() {
var charLength = $(this).val().length;
// Displays count
$('span#charCount').html(charLength + ' of 250 characters used');
// Alerts when 250 characters is reached
if($(this).val().length > 250)
$('span#charCount').html('<strong>You may only have up to 250 characters.</strong>');
});
```

**Reference**

http://coda-clips.com/textarea-character-count-jquery